# xvfb-run with melt hangs

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, xvfb, mlt

We are using melt utility to flatten vidoes. in it there is a plugin called kdenlivetitle. this plugin imposes title text on video but it requires X server. for that we are using xvfb-run but it hangs in-between sometime. Below is the output of "ps"

```
root@ip-10-112-249-15:/home/ubuntu# ps -ef| grep melt
root      5632 32532  0 03:44 ?        00:00:00 sudo /usr/local/scripts/melt_title.sh
```

/usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt EXP_temp.mp4
    root      5633  5632  0 03:44 ?        00:00:00 sh /usr/local/scripts/melt_title.sh   /usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt EXP_temp.mp4

//melt_title.sh has command which running belove

```
root      5634  5633  0 03:44 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -e  /var/log/xvfb.log --server-args=-screen 0 1920x1080x24 melt    /usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt -consumer avformat:EXP_temp.mp4 acodec=aac ab=384k ar=48000 vcodec=libx264 g=10
root      5650  5634  0 03:44 ?        00:01:17 melt /usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt -consumer avformat:EXP_temp.mp4 acodec=aac ab=384k ar=48000 vcodec=libx264 g=10
```

could it be because of this command running simultaneously? if it is i can restrict it to one at a time.

if you require any of other log or output please provide me how to get it.

Thanks in advanced.